# Power Tool Currently Hooked to 220V 3-Phase

Tags: three-phase

I was going to purchase a power tool that is currently hooked to 220V 3-Phase electric service.
What would I need to do in order for this device to operate in my residential garage?
Any clever ideas?
Average costs?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the tool.

Comment: What is available in your residential garage, one phase or three phase?

Comment: Two choices - replace the motor with a single-phase one, or buy a converter to generate three-phase from single phase.  Either way, the power rating of the tool makes all the difference to the cost.

Comment: Thank you all for the information so far.  I need ideas and options as this can get cost prohibitive.  The residential garage is one phase.  The tool is a table saw with a 5 HP motor that runs on 240V, 3-phase electrical service.  Is there some way to know if the motor can operate on single phase despite 3-phase being "optimal"?  Regarding the replacement of the motor, that seems simple and logical.  Is there anything inherently different about the output of a 1phase vs three phase if both motors are rated at the 5HP?  Of course I mean in the practical aspects of the machine not the L1, L2, L3

Comment: *single phase available…5 HP 3-phase motor that runs on 240V* edit this into the question body.

Comment: At 5 HP, local regulations prohibit using it with a *run capacitor* (+ optionally a *start* capacitor) more likely than not. At the same voltage, you wouldn't even get half the power: ready to use a blade not even half the diameter?

Comment: (Um - 5 HP will be almost 20 A even at 240 V, right?)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how over-specified the present motor is for the tool. Some 3 phase motors, once started, will run happily on single phase, at more or less full speed, but with reduced maximum torque. Try the tool out on single phase before you buy.

'Once started'. Starting would also be at reduced torque. It depends what the startup load on the tool is, so a grinder wheel would have less trouble than a compressor for instance. Try starting with a motor start capacitor to the third phase input.

Comment: Thank you very much, Neil.  It is fun to discuss this :) It is a table saw that is rated at 5HP and 240V so I was wondering if I could design something that would operate the machine if I have the 240V outlet installed and try to "skip" the 3 phase.  I am not interesting in the full 5HP rating and would be OK with reduced performance to a degree that the machine remains functional for most general purposes.  Thank you for what you may add to the discussion.